# Using dash bootstrap components not affecting layout

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I'm trying to format my dashapp using `dbc.Row` and `dbc.Col` such that my search bar has a submit button right beside it instead of below.

Below is my code that I've followed in documentations to specify my row and column. I've also played around with the `width` parameter to no effect. And also see image below showing no effect. Please advise.

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    # Title
    html.H2(
        children="Faculty Dashboard",
        style={'textAlign':'center', 'color': colors['text']}
    ),
    html.Hr(),

    html.Div(
        children=[
            html.H6(
                children="Faculty Information:",
                style={'textAlign':'center', 'color': colors['text'], 'margin-left': '20px'}
            ),
            html.Div([  
                dbc.Row([                            
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Input(
                        id='faculty-name',
                        type='text',
                        placeholder='Enter faculty name:',
                        debounce = True,
                        style={
                            'height': '40px',
                            'lineHeight': '60px',
                            'borderWidth': '1px',
                            'borderRadius': '5px',
                            'textAlign': 'center',
                            'margin': '10px'
                    })),
                    dbc.Col(html.Button(id='submit-button', type='submit', children='Submit'), width=3)
                ]),
                dbc.Row([html.Div(id='fac-info')])
            ]),
            html.Hr(),
            
            html.H6(
                children="Popular Publications:",
                style={'textAlign':'center', 'color': colors['text'], 'margin-left': '20px'}
            ),
            html.Div(id='pub-info')
        ],
        style={
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'vertical-align': 'top',
            'margin-left': '20px',
        }
    ),
....
```

[image: snipshot]

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you just set `width` for column that content button but not input.

Please try to use below code:

```
    html.Div([  
        dbc.Row([                            
            dbc.Col([dcc.Input(
                id='faculty-name',
                type='text',
                placeholder='Enter faculty name:',
                debounce = True,
                style={
                    'height': '40px',
                    'lineHeight': '60px',
                    'borderWidth': '1px',
                    'borderRadius': '5px',
                    'textAlign': 'center',
                    'margin': '10px'
            })],width=9),
            dbc.Col([html.Button(id='submit-button', type='submit', children='Submit')], width=3,style={'padding-top' : 15})
```